# Why is ST_Distance_Sphere using WGS 80?

Tags: postgis, wgs84

PostgreSQL's [ST_Distance_Sphere function](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) calculates the distances on earth:

```
float ST_Distance_Sphere(geometry pointlonlatA, geometry pointlonlatB);
```

In its documentation, there is a peculiar note:

> This function currently does not look at the SRID of a point geometry and will always assume its in WGS 80 long lat.

My geometries are stored in WGS 84, which seems to be the [de-facto standard for storing geospatial entities in PostgreSQL](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html), an the [reference coordinate system used by the GPS system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System).

**Why does `ST_Distance_Sphere` uses WGS 80? Should I expect any significant error due to the coordinate system difference?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't use WGS80.   You are looking at old documentation for version 1.4.  In more up to date documentation it states WGS84 is assumed.  See [here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) where it states:

> This function currently does not look at the SRID of a geometry and
>   will always assume its in WGS 84 long lat.

The version you quote from (1.4) also only implemented ST_Distance_Sphere for points (being prior to 1.5).  The documentation since 1.4 all states that WGS84 is used.  I suspect that the reference to 'WGS80' in the v1.4 documentation is a typo.  I know of WGS60, WGS66 and WGS72.  There is a GRS80 but I'm unaware of a WGS80 (confirmed with a quick check on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=WGS80&srtext=Search))

In any event, the speed of st_distance_sphere over st_distance_spheroid comes from the the former's use of approximating a spherical Earth of radius 6370986 meters (which has been the same since v1.3 - which is another reason why I suspect a typo).  So use st_distance_sphere for speed and st_distance_spheroid for greater accuracy.

Comment: Not really that silly as I think it is a typo (see my edits)!  Better to ask than remain confused!

Comment: WGS84 is only assumed if there is no SRID see Mike T's answer below: gis.stackexchange.com/a/154769/6052  **the docs are still wrong** and Mike T is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The [postgis 2.1 manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) states that it assumes WGS84.  And uses a sphere to return a faster result than [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) which returns the minimum distance between two lon/lat geometries given a particular spheroid.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the manual is incorrect. If the SRID is unknown, it is assumed to be WGS84. For PostGIS 2.0 and later, the radius of the spheroid is obtained by [calculating the average mean radius with the data provided by the SRID](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191279/2639).  Let's add a Martian projection system for fun:

```
SELECT Postgis_version()
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) VALUES
(49900, 'IAU2000', 49900, '+proj=longlat +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +no_defs ', 'GEOGCS["Mars 2000",DATUM["D_Mars_2000",SPHEROID["Mars_2000_IAU_IAG",3396190.0,169.89444722361179]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Decimal_Degree",0.0174532925199433]]');
```

Now calculate some distances 1°W of [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island):

```
SELECT
  ST_Distance_Sphere(p1, p2) AS default,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(p1, 4326), ST_SetSRID(p2, 4326)) AS wgs_84,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(p1, 4269), ST_SetSRID(p2, 4269)) AS grs_1980,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(p1, 49900), ST_SetSRID(p2, 49900)) AS mars
FROM (
    SELECT ST_MakePoint(0, 0) AS p1, ST_MakePoint(0, 1) AS p2
) f;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------
default  | 111195.079734632
wgs_84   | 111195.079734632
grs_1980 | 111195.079734022
mars     | 59158.400417482
```

So you can see that there are very minor differences between WGS84 and GRS80. Obviously Mars has a different radius than Earth.